# ASP.NET MultiPlayer Game

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays

I am working on a project and was hoping I could get a little insight of the best way to create this..

I want to be able to create a multiplayer game using Ajax, ASP.NET, and javascript.

Immediate questions I have before I implement the game, what is the best way to create a game without a database?

My initial thoughts are create a shared object somehow like a "game", which consist of 2 "players", 1 "cardDeck" (which is composed of 52 "card"(s) and 2 "playersHand". (where " " is a class)

As far as 2 player's would it be easier to prompt the user to enter a new game, or enter a session ID?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by a database? A database stores information, a server communicates and processes requests. A server can communicate with a database. I assume that you'll be using NodeJS, so it'd be easy just to store temporary things in arrays and other compound data-types.

You could definitely create a shared object.

One player could initialize a game, and then provide a temporary session ID, which the other player could then enter.

Since the best or most convenient method of implementation is for you to decide.

Comment: I meant without a database.. I know what one is.

Comment: Ok. What would you use the database for?

Comment: I mean I guess nothing in this case.. Just not entirely sure how I can share an object between the two players.

Comment: Well, since ASP.NET has jQuery, you may be able to use its events. Perhaps the web page could send its events to the ASP.NET server, which would handle the logic? That's probably what you wanted :p.